# Is it possible to create GCP resources using terraform without changing main.tf & varaible.tf everytime?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Shared example is for GCP VM creation. Goal here is to create 5 different VM's in a project without changing main.tf & varaible.tf everytime.  I am able to successfully create a VM with the below module when i do terraform apply for first time, but to create another VM - what i am doing is, updating **new** VM **"name"** in variables.tfvars. Then when i do terraform apply, TF is deleting the existing VM which was created in the first run and then trying to create a new VM. But my aim is to have a module where i shouldn't be changing main.tf & varaible.tf everytime and have different VMs created. Is this achievable via terraform OR any possible solution please?

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  project      = var.project
  name         = var.name
  machine_type = var.machine-type
  zone         = var.zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      }
      disk_encryption_key_raw = "5DPzBhkLSfXk8kg="
}

  network_interface {
    subnetwork_project = var.host_project_id
    subnetwork = var.subnet_name
  }

  metadata = {
    block-project-ssh-keys = true,
    enable-oslogin         = true,
    serial-port-enable     = false
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 -y && echo '<!doctype html><html><body><h1>our collaborative problem-solving ability, and the warm professionalism of our teams.!</h1></body></html>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html"

  // Apply the firewall rule to allow external IPs to access this instance
  tags = ["http-server"]
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the instance"
}

variable "machine-type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Machine type of the instance"
}

variable "region" {
  type = string
  description = "Region in which the instance has to be created"
}

variable "zone" {
  type        = string
  description = "Zone in which the instance has to be created"
}

variable "project" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the project"
}

variable "network" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the subnet"
}

variable "host_project_id" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the host project for network"
}

variable "subnet_name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the subnet"
}
```

**variables.tfvars**

```
name            = "test-2"
machine-type    = "n1-standard-4"
region          = "us-east4"
zone            = "us-east4-a"
project         = "demoapp"
network         = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/network-dev/global/networks/vpc-1"
host_project_id = "network-dev"
subnet_name     = "subnet-1"
```

**Created a folder structure module as per below comments however facing issues during deletion.**

```
project
|-- sa-01
|   `-- variable.tfvars
|-- sa-02
|   `-- variable.tfvars
|-- main.tf
`-- variables.tf
```

**sa-01/variables.tfvars**

```
sa_name         = ["sa-test1","sa-test2","sa-test3"]

sa_dis_name     = ["sa-test1","sa-test2","sa-test3"]
```

**sa-02/variables.tfvars**

```
sa_name         = ["sa-test1","sa-test2","sa-test3"]

sa_dis_name     = ["sa-test1","sa-test2","sa-test3"]
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_service_account" "sa_npe_policy" {
  count        = "${length(var.sa_name)}"
  project      = "tools-npe"
  account_id   = "${element(var.sa_name, count.index)}"
  display_name = "${element(var.sa_dis_name, count.index)}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable sa_name {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "SA Name"
}

variable sa_dis_name {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "SA Display Name"
}
```

Comment: There are several solutions here. You can declare additional resources with different argument values. You can use the `for_each` or the old `count` meta-argument. You can manage this as a module and use similar solutions. Could you elaborate on your requirements to determine which of the solutions would be best?

Comment: That's how Terraform works. ;-) In Terraform you define how your infrastructure should look like and then on `terraform apply`, Terraform will make it happen. If you later change how your infra should look like (e.g. different VM name), then Terraform will change that for you.
If you want to create multiple VMs with a similar template, there are different options, e.g. use your above code as a module and reuse it from multiple other (root) modules. Please elaborate a bit on the infra you want to create, how these VM relate to each other and we might be able to help better.

Comment: Thanks both for the response. Actually these VM's doesn't relate to each other and they are independent. Only thing trying to achieve is, let it be project creation or VM creation in GCP - i want to create a TF module where i don't need to modify the main.tf everytime, rather i want to make all declaration as static and only change required fields whenever new changes are needed.. Suppose from above example, if i want to make changes to create another VM in different project then i will be updating VM name, project name and running TF plan again. Similarly for project creation.

Comment: Actual scenario with above code happening is - i create a VM first and then i change VM name & create another VM. TF is deleting the old one and creating new. Looks this is expected behavior for my code.. Please suggest a alternative way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches how you could achieve this, each with their own pros and cons...

#### Multiple `.tfvars` files and multiple `.tfstate`files

You define multiple variables files, one for each of your VMs aka environments. When applying your terraform definition, you have to specify which variable file to use and where to store the state file of this terraform config:

```
terraform apply -var-file=./env1/terraform.tfvars -state ./env1/env1.tfstate
```

I would recommend to store variables file and state file for each of your environments together in a dedicated folder. In this case you would end up with a folder structure like:

```
project
|-- env1
|   |-- env1.tfstate
|   `-- terraform.tfvars
|-- env2
|   |-- env2.tfstate
|   `-- terraform.tfvars
|-- env3
|   |-- env3.tfstate
|   `-- terraform.tfvars
|-- main.tf
`-- variables.tf
```

**Pro**

- Is close to what I understand your requirements are.
- Might be a good [KISS solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) for home use.

**Con**

- In the setup described above, you would store variable definitions of all VMs in one repository together with the module definition (your `*.tf` files).
- While you could of course store tour variable files in separate repos instead of a subfolder, I guess this structure would get confusing very quickly.

Nota bene: This works well if you are using a local backend in terraform. I have not tested it with a remote backend, but I assume it would require further improvement.

---

#### Working with modules

You create a module folder just with your `main.tf` and `variables.tf` but without your `variables.tfvars`. The you create a separate folder for each of your VMs and each of them with an own  `main.tf` which includes your module as follows:

```
module "vm" {
  source = "../path/to/your/module"
  # or: source = "git::https://github.com/yourorg/yourrepo//path/to/your/module"


  name            = "test-2"
  machine-type    = "n1-standard-4"
  region          = "us-east4"
  zone            = "us-east4-a"
  project         = "demoapp"
  network         = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/network-dev/global/networks/vpc-1"
  host_project_id = "network-dev"
  subnet_name     = "subnet-1"
}
```

**Pro**

- Works instantly with remote backends.
- You can separate the infra parameters for different vms/environments/projects from each other and from the module definition.

**Con**

- Might deviate from your intended solution.

---

#### Terraform Workspaces

In general [Terraform Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) could also be a means to solve this, so I just want to mention them for the sake of completeness. However, I see them more suitable for use cases in which you need to manage equivalent environments in different stages (dev,test, prod) or regions etc.

Comment: Thanks @stdrom for the response. I have updated my new module in the question section. From the module, i ran the TF apply - i am able to create all 3 serviceaccount. However when i remove serviceaccounts  "sa-test1","sa-test2", from variable.tfvars and then when i do terraform apply - TF is deleting all 3 service account and adding "sa-test3" again.. Though it is an expected TF behaviour, is there way to avoid the deleting/recreation happening on "sa-test3" since i wanted only to delete "sa-test1" & ""sa-test2"?

Comment: @Surendar I just answered a similar question. Please check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71930414/18681649