# Planning to use reusable TF module to create GCP resource using .tfvars file and need post destroy of middle resource next resource shouldn't recreate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

We are testing reusable terraform module to create GCP resources and same we are able to achieve using count variable. now we have an challenge to decommission/destroy one/two of the in between created resources. while destroying previously created resources making other resources to be recreated.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_service_account" "sa_npe_policy" {
      ~ account_id   = "sa-test13" -> "sa-test11" # forces replacement
      ~ display_name = "sa-test13" -> "sa-test11"
      ~ email        = "sa-test13@gcp-prj-npe.iam.gserviceaccount.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id           = "projects/gcp-prj-npe/serviceAccounts/sa-tegcp-prj-npe.iam.gserviceaccount.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name         = "projects/gcp-prj-npe/serviceAccounts/sa-test13@gcp-prj-npe.iam.gserviceaccount.com" -> (known after apply)
        project      = "gcp-prj-npe"
      ~ unique_id    = "111295737867502004228" -> (known after apply)
    }

  # google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[2] will be created
  + resource "google_service_account" "sa_npe_policy" {
      + account_id   = "sa-test13"
      + display_name = "sa-test13"
      + email        = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + name         = (known after apply)
      + project      = "gcp-prj-npe"
      + unique_id    = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Here we are trying to remove sa-test11 which is impacting next resource sa-test13 to be replaced with sa-test11.

something we are looking for without recreate/replace with already created resource we need to delete any one of the resource in middle.

Comment: Your output rather suggests that you add a third instance in a list of resources that previously contained two instances. Would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that the output you posted suggests that you are trying to add a third resource instead of deleting one, I will try to explain the general approach you could take.

Assuming your initial code looks simlar like the folowing and you now want to remove `satest12`:

```
variable "sa_name" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["satest11", "satest12", "satest13"]
}


resource "google_service_account" "sa_npe_policy" {
  count        = length(var.sa_name)
  account_id   = var.sa_name[count.index]
  display_name = var.sa_name[count.index]
  project      = "gcp-prj-npe"
}
```

If you just remove `"satest12"` from the list Terraform will suggest you to delete `satest12` and `satest13` and afterwards recreate `satest13`.

*Why is that?*

Terraform internally stores the state of your resources and each of your resources will be assigned an internal address. `satest12` has the address `google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[1]` and `satest13` has the address `google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[2]`. Now if you remove `"satest12"` the resource list only comprises two elements and thus `satest13` will get the address `google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[1]`.

Terraform - for whatever reasons - is not capable to recognize that the resource already exists at the other address, so it suggests to delete two resources and create another.

*How could you circumvent that?*

Fortunately, Terraform gives us the means to manipulate its internal state. So after removing `"satest12"` do not execute `terraform apply` immediately.
Instead execute

```
tf state mv 'google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[1]' 'google_service_account.choose_an_unused_name'
tf state mv 'google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[2]' 'google_service_account.sa_npe_policy[1]'
```

This way you

1. readdress `satest12` to an unused address
2. readdress `satest13` to the address previously used by `satest12`

If you now run `terraform apply`, Terraform will recognize that there is no need to recreate  `satest13` and will only destroy `satest12`.