# Terraform different backend for each project

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm a bit of a newbie with Terraform and still working my way through the documentation, have not yet been able to find a way to accomodate the set up I need to achieve for a specific solution and hoping that some kind soul may be able to give me a push in the right direction.

I'm trying to manage a single set of paramaterised templates which deploy everything needed to support a new application we are working on in GCP. What I am trying to achieve is being able to deploy those templates to three different environments, each environment being in a distinct GCP project, by itself.

The plan is, as per recommendations, run terraform and pass in

a) The specific .tfvars file depending on the environment/project being deployed to (dev/test/prod).

b) Use the -chdir parameter to tell Terraform to pick up all the templates from 'infra-common' folder.

The tricky part is that we want each environment (gcp project) to host it's own state file in gcs/storage.

I had been looking at workspaces but it appears that workspaces will just create state subfolders on a single backend.

Question: Can this be done or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna check if this answer explains what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71918020/18681649

Comment: Thanks! It is close, but the difference is significant. Because I need to store each environments state in it's own project (not locally like the example) this means that a unique 'backend.tf' is needed for each environment and that is where I'm struggling to find a way to stitch it all together.

I'm starting to think that workspaces but with a common GCS state subfolder for all the environments may be the only option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `--backend-config`  for this. Here's how you can achieve the desired behavior:

- Create a .config file for each environment (`dev.config`, `test.config`, `prod.config`) which contain the name of the gcs bucket (which must already exist) for the respective environment
- Specify the common backend in a single `remote_state.tf` file

---

Here's how it would look:

`config/dev.config`:

```
bucket  = "tf-state-dev"
```

`config/test.config`:

```
bucket  = "tf-state-test"
```

`config/prod.config`:

```
bucket = "tf-state-prod"
```

`remote_state.tf`:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}
```

then, you can run the init. So for example, for dev this would look like:

```
$ terraform init --backend-config=config/dev.config
```

then, you can create a workspace for the environment:

```
$ terraform workspace new dev
```

With this approach, you can use a single set of templates (you can in fact configure dynamic variables based on the current workspace).

Comment: Definitely the correct approach if unable to use TFCloud/TFE.

Comment: All workspaces use the same state backend so does this actually work?  It looks like you're setting up different buckets here.  I believe you'd only need one.

Comment: @colan you could do it with one bucket only, but generally speaking different workspaces=different environments so it makes sense to have separate buckets

Comment: @Paolo My point was that Workspaces only support a single backend for all states so you don't have a choice.  If you want multiple storage buckets, you can't use Workspaces.  You'd need to use some other mechanism, like environment variables.

Comment: What if I want to switch the entire backend? Such as gcs for one env but azurerm for another?

Answer (score 4):

What you could do (we have a project with a similar setup with a different cloud provider), is:

- use `infra-common` as a module
- instead of working with `.tfvar` files per environment, use a separate root module per environment which invokes `infra-common` as sub-module.

Your folder structure could look like:

```
project
|-- dev
|   `-- main.tf
|-- modules
|   `-- infra-common
|       |-- main.tf
|       `-- variables.tf
|-- test
|   `-- main.tf
`-- prod
    `-- main.tf
```

**`dev/main.tf`**

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tf-state-dev"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}

module "stage" {
  source = "../modules/infra-common"

  env      = "dev"
  some_var = "value"
}
```

**`prod/main.tf`**

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tf-state-prod"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}

module "stage" {
  source = "../modules/infra-common"

  env      = "prod"
  some_var = "value"
}
```

Comment: This is extremely useful! I think that the method suggested by Paolo is probably going to be simpler for me to implement, but I have saved your answer and will likely try this out in other projects and situations. Thanks!

Comment: is main.tf is not getting duplicated? ideally there should be a common folder for you app/infra code where you keep main.tf and backend.tf(whout config), and keep env folder which only keeps tfvars and backend config and pass this backend config via -backend-config option.